Python MySQL mypy typing complaining about incorrect types
I'm using python with mysql-connector and am running my code through mypy and it's complaining about types which I can't seem to get around.
for instance. I have code like this
    today = datetime.now().date()
    mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "select holiday_date from Holidays", {} )
    rows = mysql_cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        holiday_date = row[ 0 ]
        if holiday_date <= today:
            print( holiday_date )

The Holidays table has a single column as.
    holiday_date DATE NOT NULL

so I know that what will be returned will be python date objects but mypy is complaing...
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("Decimal" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("bytes" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("float" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("int" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("set[str]" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("str" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("timedelta" and "date")  [operator]
error: Unsupported operand types for <= ("time" and "date")  [operator]
note: Left operand is of type "Any | Decimal | bytes | date | float | int | set[str] | str | timedelta | time | None"

I know that the column being returned is "typed" as it described above but I'm not sure how I coerce mypy into believing that the value is a date.
Any ideas?

mysql-connector is unable to give exact types for the elements of the row tuple, only that it could be any of the types it can deserialize to. Probably best you can do is from typing import cast and holiday_date = cast(date, row[0]). This doesn't give you type safety exactly (you might be wrong about the type) but does encode your assumption about the type and ensure your code is consistent with that assumption, and will make the errors go away.

To do better than that you probably have to explore using some kind of ORM library (e.g. sqlalchemy) where you query via a model class which encodes the expected types and would error at runtime if it did not get expected types
